# VSCode not autoformatting on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, autopep8

Vscode is not formatting my code on save.

My vscode versions are thus:

- Vscode 1.37.0 (updated it as part of bug shooting, not sure previous version, but this didn't work either)
- autopep8 1.4.4 (pycodestyle: 2.5.0)

My settings.json look like this:

```
{
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=120"
    ],
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
    "python.linting.pep8Args": [
        "--max-line-length=120"
    ],
    "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/me/.python_virtualenvs/somepath"
}
```

Why is autoformatting on save not working?

Additional notes:

- This correctly formatted my file: `python -m autopep8 --max-line-length 120 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive my_dirty_code.py`
- I can see `Formatting with autopep8` in the taskbar on save

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the `Format on Save Timeout` in `Text Editor -> Formatting`.
For example set it to 2000ms.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, but using [`black`](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as a formatter, using the VScode extension [`ms-python.black-formatter`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.black-formatter) version v2022.7.13271013.

Besides configuring the settings as described on the extension page, I had to set `"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file"`.